# Where to find current mission name on HUD?

Tags: warframe

Where to find current mission name on HUD?

Aside from initially loading into a mission, I have no way to reference where I'm playing, during or after completion. This is a nuisance for me when I want to remember where I went to farm for certain items w/o constantly reverting back to wiki pages.

Am I missing something here, or is this not part of the current HUD?

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way for you to see the name of the current mission.  However, anyone who has you on their friends list can see what mission you're in as can anyone you send an invite to.

Comment: I don't think this is possible either.  However, most planets only have 1 or 2 nodes of a particular game type, so you can narrow it down a lot that way.  Most drops are also on a planetary basis, and you can (usually) tell the planet by what tileset it is.  Also, sorry to say, constantly reverting back to wiki pages is a significant part of the game for most people.